# Using onboard video for monitor to save GPU ram?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

If the monitors plugged into the gpu use a fair amount gpu ram, would switching the monitor to the onboard video on motherboard decrease this usage on the gpu?
I have an i7 6700k 4.4ghz (oc'd) and an msi m5 with 32 gb of ddr4-3000. I have a simulation thats right above the edge of my memory cap on my gpu so I get that cudafail but, I really don't want to cpu render this.

Comment: It might, if you can actually accomplish that, but it may not free enough memory for sucessfully rendering

Comment: I'll post the results shortly, I'm using two monitors now, I had read that they use between 200-350mb of gpu ram each, if this is the case switching to a single output on the motherboard should put me into the greenzone on my gpu. --- Update, the answer is yes. I was able to reduce my total gpu cost! almost 440mb going from 2 monitors on the gpu to a single on the motherboard. I also found I could split parts of my scene, into separate blends files by apending them into a new scene, and then I can recombine them in the compositor so I used openexr multilayer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes. I was able to reduce my total gpu cost! almost 440mb going from 2 monitors on the gpu to a single on the motherboard. I also found I could split parts of my scene, into separate blends files by apending them into a new scene rendering as an openexr multi layer to save all my compositor data, and compositing the two scenes together in the final version. This cut my gpu memory cost in half.